# css set other sibling div transparent but not currently I hover

Tags: html, css

What i want to do is when i hover 1 div , and make only this sibling div transparent

```
<div>DIV 1</div>
<div>DIV 2</div>
<div>DIV 3</div>
```

what is the css??

Comment: Which is the sibling?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.. ?

Answer (score 2):

Given the HTML:

```
<div>DIV 1</div>
<div>DIV 2</div>
<div>DIV 3</div>
```

To hover over `DIV 1` and affect `DIV 2`:

```
div:nth-child(1):hover + div
/* or:
div:first-child:hover + div
*/ {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo, using `:nth-child(1)`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dUDPQ/).

[JS Fiddle demo, using `:first-child`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dUDPQ/1/).

To hover over `DIV 1` and affect `DIV 3`:

```
div:nth-child(1):hover + div + div {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo, using `:nth-child(1)`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dUDPQ/2/).

Answer (score 0):

How about using a container `div`:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>DIV 1</div>
    <div>DIV 2</div>
    <div>DIV 3</div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#outer:hover div {
    opacity: .5;
}
#outer:hover div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9kD9/)

Comment: I guess this won't work since you always affect all divs which is not what the OP (seems to) want(s).

Comment: This was my take on interpreting the question, which is not clear about what sibling(s) the OP means.  Maybe you're right, let's see...

Answer (score 0):

CSS has two [sibling combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators):

the adjacent combinator affects the "direct neighbor":

```
div + div
```

> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent
>   in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   immediately precedes the element represented by the second one.

the general combinator affects a "general neighbor":

```
div ~ div
```

> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in
>   the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

Depending on what you need you could use one or the other.

Your question is very vague, but one of these might work for you:

```
div:hover + div  /* affects adjacent div */
div:hover ~ div  /* affects all sibling divs */
div:first-child:hover +|~ div /* only triggers on your first div */
```